# How to check if the view is set the specific background

Tags: android, view, background

i am trying to compare the view background to the drawable but its not working for me.

```
View v1 = options.findViewById(i);
v1.findViewById(R.drawable.back);
Drawable d = v1.getBackground();       

if(d.getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.correct_ans_back)){
    v1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.a);             
}else{
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.b);               
}
```

how to check i am getting an error here.

```
incompatible operand types Drawable.Constant State and Drawable
```

Comment: what do you need that for?

Comment: @deville i need to check if the view is set with a background? if set then change or else do soething how to do that

Comment: Comparing two drawables (potentially large objects, BitmapDrawables, for example) doesn't seem too efficient.

Comment: Store the state in some kind of `boolean` or `enum` variable. Or what you might need to do is to implement selector with custom states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Replace

```
if(d.getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.correct_ans_back))
```

with

```
if(d.getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.correct_ans_back).getConstantState())
```

This will solve the `incompatible operand types Drawable.Constant State and Drawable` error.

2) If you are not able to compare two bitmaps, then you can use the below method.

```
public boolean compareDrawable(Drawable d1, Drawable d2){
    try{
        Bitmap bitmap1 = ((BitmapDrawable)d1).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream1);
        stream1.flush();
        byte[] bitmapdata1 = stream1.toByteArray();
        stream1.close();

        Bitmap bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable)d2).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream2);
        stream2.flush();
        byte[] bitmapdata2 = stream2.toByteArray();
        stream2.close();

        return bitmapdata1.equals(bitmapdata2);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return false;
}
```

3) OR , you can assign two different `TAG` to the background images and compare the `TAG` only instead of comparing drawable directly.
You can also set background's `TAG` as drawable's id and compare it as described below,

```
Object tag = bgView.getTag(); 
int backgroundId = R.drawable.bg_image;
if( tag != null && ((Integer)tag).intValue() == backgroundId) {
   //do your work.
}
```

Comment: will it now compare the 2 backround images?

Comment: i am trying to compare it in ontouch cancel by using TAG but not working ? any idea

Comment: Answer updated, hope this will solve the problem or you will get some hint about solving it.