# Android: Comparing images in a ImageButton and resource

Tags: java, android, bitmap, drawable

I have an ImageButton and it has a background set to it like this:

```
final ImageButton[][] gridButton = new ImageButton[5][5];
gridButton[0][0] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
gridButton[0][0].setImageResource(ButtonIcon.l[0]); //ButtonIcon.l[0] is an image ID from my resources folder.

gridButton[0][0].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        ButtonIcon justAnObject = new ButtonIcon();
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int newId = justAnObject.changeIconId(((BitmapDrawable)gridButton[0][0].getDrawable()).getBitmap());
//          int newId = justAnObject.changeIconId(gridButton[0][0].getDrawable());
            gridButton[0][0].setImageResource(newId);

        }
    });
```

In the buttonIcon class, I have a method making the comparison:

```
public int changeIconId(Bitmap object){
    if (object == ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.load0)).getBitmap()){
        return R.drawable.load1;
    }
    else return R.drawable.straight0;
}
```

All the IDs refer to images in my resources folder. I'm not quite sure how to approach this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: in general , you want to compare two bitmaps right?

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/14353043/1329126

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to compare two bitmaps

```
public boolean equals(Bitmap bitmap1, Bitmap bitmap2) {
    ByteBuffer buffer1 = ByteBuffer.allocate(bitmap1.getHeight() * bitmap1.getRowBytes());
    bitmap1.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer1);

    ByteBuffer buffer2 = ByteBuffer.allocate(bitmap2.getHeight() * bitmap2.getRowBytes());
    bitmap2.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer2);

    return Arrays.equals(buffer1.array(), buffer2.array());
}
```

**After your update **

#### Comparing two drawables

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)fDraw).getBitmap();
Bitmap bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable)sDraw).getBitmap();

if(bitmap == bitmap2)
    {
        //Code blcok
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try that. Is there any similar way to compare drawables? Or should I convert them to bitmaps and use this way (like I was trying)?